# Create in app settings

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my app i have a Settings page, where user can set some settings with different logic. The question: how to create settings like standard device settings:

[image]

I guess it is a table view. But should i configure each table row and create another views for each row ? Or there is a default widget to configure settings ? Because i did my settings like this:

[image]

And do all logic manually :(

Comment: that is a tableview with multiple section...and i think it is static tableview so some of the row have its view controller ,it is depend upon your requirements

Comment: Do for each text field row or select row they use different views?:( it's a lot of same logic and code:(

Comment: Why don't you post more details about your application, and what it should do? Helping you could be easier.

Comment: Have a look to my answer, but it would be great it you were clearer and showing some more code of what you did.

Comment: So I have a field with zip code and select list with states. I should create two custom cells and two views ? One view will display text field, another will display table with states? And they should connect with setting view by segue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings in the "official" app is composed of a `UITableView` but with static cells.
Each row is configured manually and separately.

*Note : To have static cells, you have to create a `UITableViewController` instance.*